# DocuSign JWT Authentication .p12 needed instead of PEM

Tags: docusignapi, pem, p12

i am trying to work with docusign JWT.
The environment where i develop only supports .p12 files. Docusign offers me a pem file. Is there a way to convert the .pem into a .p12 or even better to generate a .p12 directly from docusign ?

When trying to convert it to a .p12 i need the certificates. Can anybody help me on where i can get the corresponding / matching certificates ? I am completely lost.

Thanks!

BR
Martin

Answer (score 1):

Procedure

1. Go to https://www.openssl.org/community/binaries.html
2. Download and install version 1.0.1p.
3. 

Run the following command format from the OpenSSL installation bin folder.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out Cert.p12 -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -passin pass:root -passout pass:root
```

[(original source)](https://help.hcltechsw.com/appscan/Standard/9.0.3/en-US/t_ConvertthepfxCertificatetopemFormat068.html)

However, you only need the private key to [get a token using JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/).
.p12 files include both.
If you can extract the private key from them - you can use it. DocuSign doesn't provide
an SDK support to work with a .p12 file, but there are things in the web you can look into:

https://www.ssl.com/how-to/export-certificates-private-key-from-pkcs12-file-with-openssl/

Comment: Hi Inbar
thanks for your answer!
I have to use it in SAP. There I can only import a .p12 file, even though i will only need the private part of the certificate.
I have already tried to run the statement you posted. I get an error "unable to load certificates". Am i right that the cert.pem is the public key i get from Docusign ?

Comment: AFAIK the keys are just given as plain text and you can copy/paste them into any file you want.

Comment: Inbar is correct that we don't support .p12 files. For our SDKs I believe the PEM file consists of the standard PEM format with a private key like this:

Initial Data to be processed

-----Begin [Label]-----

private key info

-----End [Label]-----


RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7468

As long as the file follows that format it should still work.

Comment: @martin if this is resolved, please mark it such. Feel free to post new questions.

Comment: HI Inbar
it is not solved so far. But it i am in contact with docusign on this issue. thanks for your help!